# Is it possible to add a code block after every procedure in visual studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering if it is possible for Visual Studio to automatically insert a custom Code block after every Sub or function.

So Everytime you declare a new function it adds the code block. For Example

```
Sub dothis()
'*******************************************
'Name: Sub dothis()
'Function:
'Variables:
'Calls
'Called By
'Last Modified
'Author
'*******************************************
```

Then you can fill in the information.

Comment: Why oh why?  Name : unnecessary (it's right there!).  Function : should be obvious, if not - refactor.  Variables : why?  They're right there; if there are too many, the sub is too big - refactor.  Calls : see - variables.  Called By : right-click, find all instances.  Last Modified : don't you use version control?  Author : looking for someone to blame?

Comment: How do you comment your code?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/coding-without-comments.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, XML comments are already a built in to Visual Studio as a way to document your code in a form that is easily consumed by Intellisense or compiled into a document by some third-party tool.  This would be much more preferrable to entering your own custom documentation format.

To add an XML comment to a method or class, simply type `'''` (`///` in C#) on the line before the method or class you would like to document.  Visual Studio will automatically pre-populate a comment block based on the method you are commenting.  If you would like to add custom fields that are populated in addition to the defaults, you can certainly do so.  I've never done it myself but [This Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lisa/archive/2010/05/25/how-to-customize-the-xml-comments-that-are-inserted-by-the-visual-basic-code-editor.aspx) will show you how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Though, I have to wonder why you would want to in the first place. The standard for documenting .NET code is [XML doc comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172652%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Plus, having fields to list callers, callees, and variables just adds unnecessary maintenance overhead. Certain documentation generators may be able to extract that information automatically anyway.